# When using a regular expression to rewrite URLs in Apache, can I use the HTML title tag in the new URL?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have some funky URLs, like this:

> (some domain.com) /cs/Satellite?c=TA_Parent&childpagename=Taconic%2FTA_Parent%2FProductModel&cid=1347209502190&pagename=GST%2FDispatcher

I want to match this:

> /cs/Satellite?c=TA_Parent&childpagename=Taconic%2FTA_Parent%2FProductModel&cid=

and replace it with some text (say, `/product-category/`), and then either use this

> 1347209502190

and delete the

> &pagename=GST%2FDispatcher

OR -

replace `1347209502190` with the page title from the HTML

So - I end up with either this

> (some domain.com) /product-category/1347209502190

OR this

> (some domain.com) /product-category/product-name

Is that possible - if the product-name would need to be pulled from the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You likely want a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^product-category/([0-9]+)/?$ /cs/Satellite?c=TA_Parent&childpagename=Taconic%2FTA_Parent%2FProductModel&cid=$1&pagename=GST%2FDispatcher [QSA,NC,L]
```

That will look for requests to product-category/[PRODUCT ID] and silently rewrite it to actually ask the server for the much longer URL. The `$1` in the longer URL inserts the matched item from the regex (`([0-9]+)`)

If you wanted to also replace it with the product name, you would need a much longer set of rewrite rules to match each product name that you would want to put in your site's Apache `.conf` file rather than an `.htaccess` as the `.htaccess` file is parsed with every request where as the site configuration is loaded at startup. If there are probably products added and removed fairly frequently, file maintenance could become an issue.